# Does the Reputation Graph indicate the results of a ReCalc?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-graph, reputation-recalc

If you look at the [reputation tab of my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top), the graph ends at a score of 12k5, my actual score is 14k8.

I have been deleting some answers lately, some with votes. Could it be that the graph is showing what a ReCalc would do?

Comment: You deleted answers worth 2k rep?

Comment: I think a little less, I didn't keep track.

Comment: wow, that's a lot of rep to delete away

Comment: Why are you deleting posts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding up all the green numbers and subtracting all the red numbers gives 12211. So that's the reputation you'd have from all current questions and answers.

**Edit:** I hadn't realized that this list also includes reputation used and granted for bounties - given that it does, you can probably trust this number. Keep in mind, rep from deleted answers, including answers to deleted or migrated questions, doesn't count.

---

At one time, I had a Greasemonkey script written to calculate your actual reputation from the graph... But this was never perfectly accurate, and the addition of the /reputation page (for instance, [your Stack Overflow reputation audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation)) makes this unnecessary.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the rep graph does list bounties.

Comment: Nevermind, I see that you're right...

Comment: I don't think I ever collected a bounty. How do I get **all** the red and green points? I can only get a 60-day window at the most.

Comment: @Henk: i've added a script.

Comment: @Shog9: you have allowed me to sleep again at night. Now I know that the difference between current rep and real rep is only 110 points. :)

Comment: @Shog9: Jon Skeet shows: 94414   is there a bug of some kind maybe?

Comment: @Shog9: This is pretty darn cool though.  Love it :)

Comment: @RSolberg: I can't vouch for the accuracy, since it only adds up what's returned by the reputation graph service: if something is missing from that, then it'll be missing from the calculated rep. And it wouldn't surprise me to learn that the graph is missing *something*; otherwise, recalcs would be a lot faster & easier!

Comment: It misses -1 scores from downvotes you did yourself. And there must be more, because for some reason my recalculated score (on SO) comes out *higher* than it is now. And I don't think you could ever *gain* from a recalc?

Comment: @sth: i've gained from past re-calcs. The most obvious reason for this is that deleted, down-voted posts (those that you down-voted and those of yours that others down-voted) no longer subtract from the reputation. And you are correct: the former (the cost of your own down-votes) isn't accounted for by this script (although it probably could be: subtract your 344 down-votes from the script's score, and you're only 68 points above where the site currently shows you).

Comment: @Shog9: Yeah, you're right, I just realized that too. But I would be surprised if I got 68 down-votes on now deleted answers. And I also don't have any posts that got deleted as offensive/spam, AFAIK. Hmm...

Comment: It would only have to be 34 down-votes @ -2 per down-vote. And I have no idea if SO counts votes that have been deleted - if you down-voted some bad posts that are now gone, those could have contributed to this as well! Only way to find out is to ask a moderator to recalculate your rep for real... ;-)

Comment: Alright, I was curious, so I requested a recalc. My rep before the recalc was 14137, after the recalc it dropped to 14054. The fake recalc estimation was 14543 (not counting 347 downvotes). This **did not change** when the recalc was done, it is still estimating the same value. So the fake recalc script calculates something not depending on the "denormalized" reputation score, but it also doesn't quite capture all aspects of the real reputation (Not quite sure what the missing information could be...).

Comment: Interesting... 142 points (after subtracting the cost of down-votes) seems a pretty big difference; i wonder what else is going on? Anyway, thanks for taking one for the team. ;-)