# Reputation graph level is lower than actual

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-graph

I just hit 10k on stack-overflow, and I noticed that my rep graph ends up at what looks like just over 9000 (*cough*).

That's quite a mismatch. I hear there are problems with bounty rep not being counted, but I don't think I've ever set or won a bounty.

I'm not sure what the cause could be.. but perhaps someone could look into it.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm on about:

[10,198 rep but graph is below 10,000 http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1264559803004377600.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1264559803004377600.png)

Comment: Ask for a recalc: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23531/recalc-with-talc

Comment: you are awfully precocious for a nine year old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you by any chance have a lot of posts deleted, or migrated to other sites? That, and the 100 rep bonus granted for associating accounts, are the only causes of discrepancies that I know of.

If you get your rep recalculated, can you post a screenshot here of your graph and rep immediately afterwards for comparison?  You know, for science...