# Rough Reputation Lost Estimating Program for New Reputation Rule

Tags: discussion, reputation, lost-reputation

This goes through the JSON API for reputation amounts for questions and halved the total gain points. The loop is needed because there is 90 days limitation on the range.

```
import sys,time,urllib2 as u2,json

A=sys.argv[1:]
U,S=int(A[0]),A[1:] and A[1] or "stackoverflow.com"
t,c,g=0x1ca55fc00,time.time()*1000,0

while True:
 u="http://%s/users/rep-graph/%d/%d/%d"%(S,U,c-t,c)
 d=json.loads(u2.urlopen(u).read())
 if not d:break
 g+=sum(x['Gain'] for x in d if x['IsQ'])
 c-=t
 time.sleep(1)

print "Your reputation is expected to be down around",g/2,"points",
```

Usage:

```
 filename.py YOURID
```

Example for Jeff

```
 filename.py 1
```

You can specify the site name like superuser.com, serverfault.com like

```
 filename.py 1 superuser.com
```

As a result, Jon Skeet is going to lose **688** points, and Jeff is going to lose **2286** points

**PS**: I noticed that above numbers are not divisible by 5, reps cap is the only I can think of for that case.

Let me know your ideas about bugs or improvements.

Comment: I don't think those numbers are right.  Any amount of rep lost should be evenly divisible by 5, no?

Comment: Grew up on code golf? :-P

Comment: may be because of reputation cap @squillman, thats only I can think of

Comment: @Chris, :P thats my passion

Comment: Yes, it's most likely the rep cap. But this estimation can't account for times when a question is upvoted and then after the rep cap is hit, answers are upvoted. I suspect Jon Skeet will end up losing fewer than 100 points.

Comment: @mmyers, I am not counting the votes, I used the JSON API used in this page `/users/X?tab=reputationhistory` and which show exact reputation points gotten, and upvoted questions after rep cap isn't count, If I am not wrong.

Comment: @S.Mark: I don't mean that it's your fault, since it would be an extreme amount of effort to calculate accurately (and would probably get your IP banned for your trouble). I'm just pointing out that as you said, it's an *estimate*.

Comment: @mmyers, sure, its an estimate. I would not know how will the algorithm implement and this does not include rep recalc, so this will not be final result for sure. And I wish Jeff to allow 5 to 10 JSON request for that, only Jon Skeet reputations list request was biggest. :-)

Comment: Somebody please point me to where the new reputation rule is, I'm lost.

Comment: @Lance, http://blog.stackoverflow.com  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/):

You can use

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation

...etc. to pull a fresh and accurate rep-report for your account.

Comment: Thannnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnk you!

Answer (score 8):

Here it is in [Easy-To-Use Greasemonkey Format™](http://www.shog9.com//greasemonkey/scripts/so_question_rep_reduction_estimator.user.js)

[image: A picture of a profile just after the script has been run]

Same caveats: no allowances for the daily rep cap or bonuses, final tally may have a fractional component and none of this will be correct after the official recalc.

*After installing, click button on any user's profile page to run script. Script is done when numbers turn green. First number is estimated rep, small numbers below are total gains and losses, difference reflects change from current site-calculated rep. Based on my [fake recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23531/does-the-reputation-graph-indicate-the-results-of-a-recalc/23539#23539) script...*

Comment: +1 Great!, my python code does not include rep re-calc parts, I am learning yours now.

Comment: @S.Mark: yeah, this is likely to give somewhat different results from yours simply because there are probably other differences between current rep and rep-graph rep for most users.

Comment: Slight issues with people who have 1 reputation, which might mean that this is always 1 rep off. You may be assuming everyone starts with a rep of 0.

Comment: @Yacoby: yup - this only counts the gains/losses reported by the rep graph, so other influences (the 1 everyone starts with, the 100 for associating an account, rep capped at 1 or rep gain capped at 200...) aren't reflected. If you run it on someone who's been heavily down-voted, you can actually see a negative final rep...

Comment: @Shog9, I still can't get same results as yours, I can assume you also count till date.now right? I am getting 13417.5 points, don't know why.

Comment: my current code is here http://codepad.org/Pe9nwJkE , cannot run directly in codepad though

Comment: Can you do me? For some reason I cannot login to SO with FF

Comment: @S.Mark: not quite sure what you're doing with timespans in that code... But I did re-examine mine, and found a couple of serious bugs with how *I* was handling them: the start date (second-to-last parameter in the URL) should be at the start of a day (00:00:00) in UTC, and the end date should be 1 millisecond short of *n* days later, where *n* is >= 1 <= 90. I had been starting each day at whatever time the user joined the site, which resulted in the script returning some values twice (where days overlapped)... I suspect you're doing something similar, but based on the current time.

Comment: @Downvoter: according to this, you stand to lose something like 2670 points...

Comment: @Downvoter: I should probably mention, there's a 900pt discrepancy between your *current* rep and what the script calculates it should be... so the actual loss due to question rep halving may be considerably less (not that it matters if you lose it anyway).